# Discrete math equation: True or False

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hello I am having an issue with this problem. it goes like this:

```
There exists an n for all m such that m*n = n.
```

I am confused on how to approach this problem.

Thanks in advance!

edit: Is this true or false?

I originally thought false due to the fact that there is only one m such that the equation is valid.

Comment: $n=0$. *micdrop*

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Suppose that it's true. Then what could this mysterious $n$ be? Well whatever it is, the equation most hold for ANY $m$. For example, it should hold when $m = 2$ so that:
$$
2n = n
$$

It should also hold when $m = 42$ so that:
$$
42n = n
$$

Hmm...what could $n$ be? Is it the same $n$, no matter what $m$ we choose?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Move everything to one side, factorize, solve for $n$.